# RSpec Capybara unable to accept alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I've got below form:

```
<%= form_with url: kyc_document_upload_path, multipart: true, data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure to upload file?" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :document_type, value: item %>
  <%= f.label :file, 'Upload', name: "upload_button" %>
  <%= f.file_field :file, class: "inputfile", accept: ".pdf", onchange: 'this.form.requestSubmit()' %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to test this using Capybara. So what I did was:

```
it 'show message' do
  login_as user
  visit profile_path

  expect(page).not_to have_css '#Upload'

  attach_file("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/sample.pdf") do
    accept_alert "Are you sure to upload file?" do
      first(:label, 'Upload').click
    end
  end
  expect(page).not_to have_table
end
```

But it produces me an error:

```
Capybara::ModalNotFound:
       Unable to find modal dialog with Are you sure to upload file?
```

How to accept these alert? If I remove `accept_alert` block to be:

```
it 'show message' do
  login_as user
  visit profile_path

  expect(page).not_to have_css '#Upload'

  attach_file("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/sample.pdf") do
    first(:label, 'Upload').click
  end
  expect(page).not_to have_table
end
```

I've got an error:

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedAlertOpenError:
   unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure to upload file?}
     (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.87)
```

Comment: What line is the UnexpectedAlertOpenError coming from? Are you sure it's  coming from inside the `attach_file`  call, and not from outside it?  ie. the onchange wouldn't be triggered until after the file is attached - you'd need it to be `accept_alert(...) do attach_file ... do find(...).click end end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it looks like the alert is being triggered by the onchange handler of the file input.  That means it wouldn't be triggered until the file selection is done, which is when `attach_file` returns - therefore you've likely got the `accept_alert` in the wrong place, and instead need

```
accept_alert "Are you sure to upload file?" do
  attach_file("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/sample.pdf") do
    first(:label, 'Upload').click
  end
end
```